# Does not accept in raster calculator variable s the number QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, typeerror

I'm writing a plugin, where self.dlg.lineEdit_11.text() This number (attached image)

[image]

gives an error message

> Traceback (most recent call last): calc = QgsRasterCalculator("rastr_raznica1@1" + s, var, 'GTiff', layer2.extent(), layer2.width(), layer2.height(), entries ) TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

through processing, I appeal to the raster calculator, but he does not want to be considered `QgsRasterCalculator("rastr_raznica1@1" + s)` It does not take s the number

```
def edit_raster(self):
    entries =[]
    rastrway1=self.dlg.lineEdit_11.text()
    var= os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(rastrway1)),'rastr_sko.tif')
    tif2=  os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(rastrway1)),'rastr_raznica1.tif')
    r = self.dlg.lineEdit_10.text()
    s=float(r)
    print s
    layer2 = QgsRasterLayer(tif2, "rastr_sko")
    her_2 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    her_2.ref = 'rastr_raznica1@1'
    her_2.raster = layer2
    her_2.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append(her_2)
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator("rastr_raznica1@1" + s, var, 'GTiff', layer2.extent(), layer2.width(), layer2.height(), entries )
    calc.processCalculation()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @zhora! Try replacing `s=float(r)` with `s=str(r)` and then replace `"rastr_raznica1@1" + s` with `"rastr_raznica1@1 +" + s`.

Comment: The whole input to rastercalculator needs to be quoted, but also the rasterbands. Not sure if you have double quotes there or two times single ones. with double quotes it should look like: ""rastr_raznica1@1"+{}".format(s)